# MSMQ and Web Service : security

Tags: asmx, msmq

I have a small application running with an MSMQ to pass data. Both are on the same server.

However I was asked to change the security of the msmq so I need to know "the identity" of my web service, as it currently receives an error

> access to message queuing service denied

I've already add Network Service (to monitor the content of msmq via an ASPX page) and Admin Group, but I don't really know how to allow the service itself.

I've had no trouble adding authorization for another service which runs via Task Scheduler (and thus was set to be run under an user account).

The application is an .asmx service. I can add code if you want but everything is very basic. The trouble happens when I try to write to the queue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you clarify, please? Is the web service responsible for putting messages on a queue? Or reading messages from a queue? Also are you using system.messaging to access the queue? And yes, please post the relevant code.

Comment: The queue which the service writes to, is it remote or local to the service?

Comment: And you're getting the exception when trying to write to the queue or when the console app tries to read from the queue?

Comment: Could Audit queue access to see what account is used. I'm sure there's an easier way but that's what came to mind.

Comment: @Tom Redfern : I've edited the question for clarity's sake, so I'll also remove your and my comments, but please feel free to ask other questions.

Comment: @John Breakwell : Actually sending messages cannot be audited :/

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so answer was to add the user impersonated by the service in its web config, and it took me time to find it because, for some reason, first try didn't work.

Frag it.